# Spark: How to transform values of some selected features in LabeledPoint?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, transform, normalization

I've got a `LabeledPoint` and a list of features that I want to transform:

```
scala> transformedData.collect()
res29: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = Array((0.0,(400036,[7744],[2.0])), (0.0,(400036,[7744,8608],[3.0,3.0])), (0.0,(400036,[7744],[2.0])), (0.0,(400036,[133,218,2162,7460,7744,9567],[1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,42.0,21.0])), (0.0,(400036,[133,218,1589,2162,2784,2922,3274,6914,7008,7131,7460,8608,9437,9567,199999,200021,200035,200048,200051,200056,200058,200064,200070,200072,200075,200087,400008,400011],[4.0,1.0,6.0,53.0,6.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,11.0,17.0,48.0,3.0,4.0,113.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,28.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,4.0])), (0.0,(400036,[1589,3585,4830,6935,6936,7744,400008,400011],[2.0,6.0,3.0,52.0,4.0,3.0,1.0,2.0])), (0.0,(400036,[1589,2162,2784,2922,4123,7008,7131,7792,8608],[23.0,70.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0])), (0.0,(400036,[4830,6935,6936,400008,400011],[1.0,36.0...

val toTransform =  List(124,443,543,211,...
```

Transformation that I want to use looks like this :

1. Take the natural logarithm of (feature value+1): `new_val=log(val+1)`
2. Divide new values by maximum of new values: `new_val/max(new_val)` (if `max` not equal to 0)

How can perform this transformation for each `feature` from my `toTransform` list (I don't want to create new features, just transform old one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but not exactly straightforward. If you can transform values before you assemble vectors and labeled points then answer provided by @eliasah should do the trick. Otherwise you have to do things the hard way. Lets assume your data looks like this

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, SparseVector, DenseVector}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

val points = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.sparse(6, Array(1, 4, 5), Array(2.0, 6.0, 3.0))),
  LabeledPoint(2.0, Vectors.sparse(6, Array(2, 3), Array(0.1, 1.0)))
))
```

Next lets define small helper:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV, SparseVector => BSV, Vector => BV}

def toBreeze(v: Vector): BV[Double] = v match {
  case DenseVector(values) => new BDV[Double](values)
  case SparseVector(size, indices, values) => {
    new BSV[Double](indices, values, size)
  }
}
```

and disassemble `LabeledPoints` as follows:

```
val pairs = points.map(lp => (lp.label, toBreeze(lp.features)))
```

Now can define a transformation function:

```
def transform(indices: Seq[Int])(v: BV[Double]) = {
  for(i <- indices) v(i) = breeze.numerics.log(v(i) + 1.0)
  v
}
```

and transform pairs:

```
val indices = Array(2, 4)
val transformed = pairs.mapValues(transform(indices))
```

Finally lets find maximum values:

```
val maxV = transformed.values.reduce(breeze.linalg.max(_, _))

def divideByMax(m: BV[Double], indices: Seq[Int])(v: BV[Double]) = {
  for (i <- indices) if(m(i) != 0) v(i) /= m(i) 
  v
}

val divided = transformed.mapValues(divideByMax(maxV, indices))
```

and map to `LabelPoints`:

```
def toSpark(v: BV[Double]) = v match {
  case v: BDV[Double] => new DenseVector(v.toArray)
  case v: BSV[Double] => new SparseVector(v.length, v.index, v.data)
}

divided.map{case (l, v) => LabeledPoint(l, toSpark(v))}
```

Answer (score 2):

@zero323 is right, you'd better flatten your `LabeledPoint`s then you can do the following :

```
// create an UDF to transform
def transform(max: Double) = udf[Double,Double] { c => Math.log1p(c) / max}

// create dummy data
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).toDF("feature")

// get the max value of the feature
val maxFeat = df.agg(max($"feature")).rdd.map { case r: Row => r.getInt(0) }.max

// apply the transformation on your feature column
val newDf = df.withColumn("norm", transform(maxFeat)($"feature"))

newDF.show
// +-------+-------------------+
// |feature|               norm|
// +-------+-------------------+
// |      1|0.13862943611198905|
// |      2|0.21972245773362192|
// |      3| 0.2772588722239781|
// |      4|0.32188758248682003|
// |      5|  0.358351893845611|
// |      4|0.32188758248682003|
// |      3| 0.2772588722239781|
// |      2|0.21972245773362192|
// |      1|0.13862943611198905|
// +-------+-------------------+
```